# How to use Selectize theme in ui-select?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select2

i have problem to apply selectize theme to my ui-select in angular.js App. I followed the instruction here - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select . It seems easy enough but i can't get the input to show up,

DEMO - http://plnkr.co/edit/TFKeMTCNVuginJ31IH80?p=preview

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match> <!-- WHERE IS THE INPUT? -->
<ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
  {{color}}
</ui-select-choices>
```

that's the demo that i forked from ui-select's. As you can see, the input doesn't show up. 
What I miss here ?

Comment: Do you have the folder with templates in place?

Answer (score 2):

I had to include the [selectize css](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/master/dist/css/selectize.css) manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `multiple` from the code, the input will show up but chosen item won't be visible although the value below the input shows the correct choice.
I suspect there's something really wrong with the Selectize theme here OR this theme isn't supposed to be used for multiple anyway.

I personally use Select2 theme for when I want to have multiple choices. Even their official `Multiple demo` is Select2 theme only: [UI-select Multiple Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/juqoNOt1z1Gb349XabQ2)

If you really really want the Selectize theme - I suggest that you play with that Plunker (the official one) by changing the theme name and anything else that may be needed in order to try to get it working.

Comment: it seem you're right, when i revert to select2 theme, the problem's gone. I really want to use selectize theme since it suits with my app appearance. I'll try to use custom class to styling it